# Pods-greeter.release.xcconfig: unable to open file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I clone my React Native project than I type

```
1. npm install
```

The project has a pod file so I cd the folder to ios then type

```
2. pod install
```

clean and run the project on XCode 10

It shows the error on XCode[image]

```
Pods-greeter.release.xcconfig: unable to open file
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Did you try react-native link

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just found the solution. upgrade pod version from 1.5.X to 1.6 and type pod install again will fix it.